# Template("..").render() in Django 1.8 not allowing numeric values

Tags: python, django-1.8

I have migrated from `Django 1.6` to `Django 1.8`. This was working fine in `Django 1.6` but giving me `expected string or buffer` exception in `Django 1.8`.

Here is my code:

```
html = Template('hi {{name}}').render(Context({'name': 12}))
```

The problem here is `'name':12`. Changing it to `'name':'12'` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the traceback (which would have been helpful if included in your question), the exception is raised within Django's internationalisation/localisation code. Here is the last couple of lines of the traceback:

```
  File "/home/mhawke/virtualenvs/django_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 125, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/mhawke/virtualenvs/django_1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 409, in check_for_language
    if not language_code_re.search(lang_code):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

That looks like a bug to me as I found that `lang_code`is `None` and that is not accepted by `re.search()`. Or it might be an issue with my configuration.

You can explicitly disable localisation in the context by passing `use_l10n=False` to `Context` like this:

```
>>> html = Template('hi {{name}}').render(Context({'name': 12}, use_l10n=False))
>>> html
u'hi 12'
```

So, provided that you can pass `use_l10n` to `Context`, you have a workaround, although presumably you can't change the code otherwise you could just fix the dictionary with something like this:

```
d = {k: str(v) for k,v in {'name': 12}.items()}
html = Template('hi {{name}}').render(Context(d))
```

If you can't change the code, you can also prevent this error by changing the template to use the `escape` or `safe` filter on the `name` variable:

```
>>> html = Template('hi {{name|escape}}').render(Context({'name': 12}))
>>> html
u'hi 12'
```

Or you can use `safe` (if you know that the value *is* safe):

```
>>> html = Template('hi {{name|safe}}').render(Context({'name': 12}))
>>> html
u'hi 12'
```

But both of these feel wrong as the filter is being applied to workaround another problem, and it might mask that problem, or cause confusion to future template authors.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> c = Context()
>>> c['foo'] = 'first level'
>>> c.update({'bar': 'second level'})
{'bar': 'second level'}
>>> c.flatten()
{'True': True, 'None': None, 'foo': 'first level', 'False': False, 'bar': 'second level'}
```

From [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context.flatten)

Comment: your code will not work if we do `c.update({'bar': 13})`, and then `Template('hi {{bar}}').render(c)` which is exactly my problem.